# How do i set a listener in an activity from another class?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sms

I am working on an application that needs to read an incoming message. Now, i found out that i need to use the onReceive method from the BroadcastReceiver class. Now i got to know that java does not allow extending two classes, so how do i get it working, i have been stuck on this from a long time, please help! Also if there is some other way to do this, please do quote.

> public class SMS extends Activity {
>       Button btnSendSMS;
>       EditText txtPhoneNo;
>       EditText txtMessage;
>
> ```
> /** Called when the activity is first created. */
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
> {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.sms);        
>
>     btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
>     txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
>
>     btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
>     {
>         public void onClick(View v) 
>         {                
>             String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();                 
>             if (phoneNo.length()>0)                
>                 sendSMS(phoneNo, phoneNo);               
>             else
>                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
>                     "Please enter a valid Phone Number.", 
>                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         }
>     });        
> }
> private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
> {        
>     PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
>         new Intent(this, SMS.class), 0);                
>     SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
>     sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
> }
>
> Context context = getApplicationContext();
> Intent intent = new Intent();
> object.onReceive(context, intent); }
> ```
>
> class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
>
> ```
> private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
> private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";
>
> @Override
> public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>      Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());
>
>       Toast.makeText(context, "HI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
>             Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
>             if (bundle != null) {
>                 Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
>                 final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
>                 for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
>                     messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
>                 }
>                 if (messages.length > -1) {
>                     Toast.makeText(context, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody(), 7000).show();
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>    } }
> ```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve after you receive the message ? provide more info

Comment: @Libin actually i need to access just the last message recieved after the activity starts.

Comment: Make your `BroadcastReceiver` an inner class of your `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extend two classes (which is not possible and never required in java) to achieve your goal. For getting the last message simply create a static message variable, lets say in your SMSBroadcastReceiver and set that variable to latest message received in onreceive. This static variable can be accessed throughout your app using `SmsReceiver.latestmessage`